# Automating figure-making with PyMOL

Tags: structural-biology, 3d-structure, visualization, pymol

## What I want to do

I have a list of almost 200 PDB entries that I need to visually inspect. Luckily, the thumbnail image displayed on the PDB website (examples with [RCSB](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/1aoi) or [PDBe](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/entry/pdb/1aoi) for a well-known structure) is enough to figure out whether I want to exclude an entry for subsequent use of the resulting cleaned-up list of entries.

Now, looking up these entries one by one on the website is easy to do, but is very slow and error-prone. I need to be careful copy/pasting accession codes, and it takes a lot of time to go to my list, copy an accession code, go to the website, paste, search, and have my answer once the result page has loaded fully.

In other words, I'm lazy and I think my time would be better spent doing something more interesting than copy/pasting 200 times.

## Attempt at a solution

I figured it shouldn't be too difficult to use PyMOL with a bit of scripting to automatically fetch each entry and generate a small image (faster than ray-tracing, which I don't need for this quick inspection). Here is my attempt:

```
pdb_entries = ['1m18', '1eqz'] # The real list has almost 200 entries, but 2 are enough to test the script

for entry in pdb_entries:
    cmd.fetch(entry, async = 0, path = "./pdb-files")
    filename = "./pdb-imgs/" + entry
    cmd.png(filename, width = 600, dpi = 100, ray = 0, quiet = 0)
    cmd.delete(entry)
```

## Problem

When I save this script as `fetch-all.py` and run it from within PyMOL with the command `run fetch-all.py`, the structure files are correctly downloaded in the `./pdb-files` directory and images with names matching the PDB accession codes are generated in the `./pdb-imgs` directory. So, it seems everything works. **Except these images are just black, not showing anything of the structure.**

I tried to add `cmd.center(entry)` and `cmd.show("cartoon", entry)` before saving the PNG files, but it did not change anything. I also looked up the help page for `cmd.png()`, thinking I was missing something, but I couldn't find anything I would be obviously missing there.

Any idea? Thank you all in advance.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that this problem of black images happens with the latest PyMOL (2.2.0) and also with an older version (1.7.4).

**Edit:** when I run the commands inside the loop one by one at the PyMOL prompt, everything works fine, I get images correctly saved. It seems it doesn't work in the context of the loop only. I double checked the loop syntax and it looks fine to me (but I might be missing something; I don't know python very well).

**Edit:** I also tried `cmd.save()` instead of `cmd.png()`, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Could it be that as all your structures have different x, y and z coordinates. Therefore whereever pymol is centered  it isnt in a position where the protein is?

Comment: Therefore could be fixed by aligning all the structures so they all appear in the same x, y and z range

Comment: I tried to add cmd.center(entry) in the loop that processes each entry, to make sure that each entry gets properly centered before saving a picture. That didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using cmd.orient ?

Comment: I just gave it a try, it did not solve the problem of the black images.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem

Comment: I ended up using ChimeraX instead, which I found easier to use overall. I abandoned the idea of generating pictures and browsed the models interactively in ChimeraX (this is slower than looking at pictures, but being able to rotate the model was useful in some cases).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not concerned with a biological problem.